# Where is PyGTK for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, pygtk

Is there a binary out there for the current mac os x, python for PyGTK? I work with multiple desktop environments (mac, windows, gnome) and really consider python's lack of cross platform GUI's a problem. Does anyone know where I can find a built version of PyGTK and GTK for Mac?
I cant clone the git repository, it keeps timing out.

Comment: http://macpkg.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't use macports but it seems that jhbuild works for me. Below is the steps that I've done.

1. download gtk-osx-build-setup.sh from: `https://raw.github.com/jralls/gtk-osx-build/master/gtk-osx-build-setup.sh` and save it to your home directory.
2. fire up terminal and navigate to your home directory and run the command `sh gtk-osx-build-setup.sh`
3. the shell script will warn you that `~/.local/bin` isn't added to your environment variable to do this, edit your `.profile` file located at your home directory and `/Users/<username>/.local/bin` to your environment variable. to know more on how to edit this file check out: `http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2621/os_x_change_path_environment_variable/`
4. after that, do a `~/.local/bin/jhbuild bootstrap` command. it will download and install some necessary utilities.
5. download and install the beta version of the gtk+ osx framework at: `http://ftp.imendio.com/pub/imendio/gtk-osx/Gtk-Framework-2.14-LATEST.dmg`
6. before installing the `meta-gtk-osx-python`, you need to build and install some other packages that `jhbuild` doesn't install automatically, so what i did was i installed `libpng` by doing the command: `~/.local/bin/jhbuild build libpng`
7. you also need to install `libtiff` so do the command: `~/.local/bin/jhbuild build libtiff`
8. and also `gtk-doc` is needed so: `~/.local/bin/jhbuild build gtk-doc`
9. and finally you can now install `meta-gtk-osx-python` by doing a: `~/.local/bin/jhbuild build meta-gtk-osx-python`

Let me know if it works.

Comment: tried this too, looks like work is blocking git also...
git.gnome.org[0: 209.132.176.202]: errno=Operation timed out
fatal: unable to connect a socket (Operation timed out)

Comment: If what your doing is work related. Might as well, ask your IT department to unblock git.

Comment: Resolving ftp.imendio.com... 88.131.94.22
Connecting to ftp.imendio.com|88.131.94.22|:80... 
blink .. blink ..

Comment: the gtk-framework-2.14-latest link does not work, you can google for it, I found this link on the internet: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mokoi/files/Third%20Party/Gtk-Framework-2.14-LATEST.dmg/download?use_mirror=surfnet

Comment: I get No module named libxml2 error on gtk-doc installation - Any idea?

Comment: Detailed instructions and everything you need are available here: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK+/OSX/Building

Answer (score 39):

`brew install pygtk` worked for me (requires [homebrew](https://brew.sh/)).

Confirmed to work with OS X 10.10 too, but by default it will install it into brew's Python distribution, so if you are still using the native python, it will not find it.

Comment: This failed for me : Error: Is a directory - /usr/local/opt/fontconfig/INSTALL_RECEIPT.json  any ideas why I got that?

Comment: No idea. You should probably ask those responsible for the brew package of pygtk, brew itself, or pygtk itself, depending on if you can find out where the message came from.

Comment: It`s work for me on Mac OS X 10.10.4. By the way, I just talk it to run the sm.py.

Comment: Warning: No available formula with the name "pygtk". Did you mean pygitup?

Answer (score 11):

There is an installer for PyGTK 2.24 in test here,  [announced](http://old.nabble.com/Testing-PyGTK-installer-for-Mac-OS-X-tt31124372.html) on the PyGTK list.

UPDATE project has moved on [macpkg's sourceforge page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/macpkg/files/PyGTK/).

I couldn't make it work with [meld](http://meld.sourceforge.net/) (segmentation fault), but sample PyGTK programs work OK.

UPDATE 2 since then a new package [Py3GTK3](http://sourceforge.net/projects/macpkg/files/Py3GTK3/3.4.4/) appeared on the same sourceforge page. Haven't tested though.

Comment: I tried Py3GTK3, but in python command line, when i do: `from gi.repository import Gtk` I got errors. Did somebody succeed with it?

Answer (score 5):

There is now a mac package on [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zero-install/files/PyGTK/2.24.0/)

Comment: Can't upvote this enough. Any one looking through the answers notice this was 3 years after the accepted answer and is now the correct answer in my opinion

Comment: I managed to install, but it's still not found. Where does is install the package?

Comment: Yep! Worked for me as well.

Answer (score 2):

Download the latest package from http://sourceforge.net/projects/macpkg/files/PyGTK/ and install.

If you're just trying to use the system python, this is all you'll have to do.

If you're not, the following is how to install it with [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv), which can be installed with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/). With brew installed, you can install version pyenv and Python 2.7.8 with:

```
brew install pyenv && pyenv install 2.7.8
```

After you've done that, you'll then have copy the gtk package and its dependencies into your python installation:

```
cd /opt/gtk/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ && \
cp * ~/.pyenv/versions/2.7.8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

That's it. You can also similarly install the Py3GTK3 package which has packages for python 2.7 and 3.2 from http://sourceforge.net/projects/macpkg/files/Py3GTK3/.

Comment: A better way `export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing it using macports? [This website shows how](http://www.php-architect.com/blog/2009/02/25/installing-python-pygtk-on-mac-osx/).

Comment: Yeah, tried that before, I think rsync is a protocol blocked by our org's firewall.

sudo port -d selfupdate
rsync: failed to connect to rsync.macports.org: Operation timed out rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-35.2/rsync/clientserver.c(105) [receiver=2.6.9]
Error: Synchronization of the local ports tree failed doing rsync
Couldn't sync the ports tree: Synchronization of 1 source(s) failed

Comment: They didnt teach anything in school, just C and ASM back in my day. Sorry to have offended you.

Comment: Sorry, i think i didnt read that right. anyway I am looking at /opt/local/etc/macports/macports.conf and i see the rsync_options, and I added -e "ssh" but no luck I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: They still don't, I was using SSH to get to all the blocked websites, like youtube, or to steam music from home. :) What are you messing with the rsync config for? Just use ssh and tneel the port. http://manas.tungare.name/blog/ssh-port-forwarding-on-mac-os-x/

Comment: what would the command line look like? Do i need a middle server? this has become an all day affair.

Comment: @RonaldoNascimento instead of 'rsync' macports can use http also. IIRC, you need to modify /opt/local/etc/macports/sources.conf file.