# How to install GTK+/PyGTK on OSX?

Tags: macos, pygtk, gtk

I'm trying to install PyGTK on OSX 10.6 (snow leopard). I have followed this topic [Where is PyGTK for Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164949/where-is-pygtk-for-mac-os-x).

When I run the last command :

```
~/.local/bin/jhbuild build meta-gtk-osx-python
```

I have the following error :

```
*** Checking out gtk+ *** [10/18]
*** Configuring gtk+ *** [10/18]
autoreconf -fis && ./configure --prefix /Users/smu/gtk/inst --libdir '/Users/smu/gtk/inst/lib' --with-gdktarget=quartz --disable-static
libtoolize: putting auxiliary files in `.'.
libtoolize: linking file `./ltmain.sh'
libtoolize: putting macros in AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR, `m4'.
libtoolize: linking file `m4/libtool.m4'
libtoolize: linking file `m4/ltoptions.m4'
libtoolize: linking file `m4/ltsugar.m4'
libtoolize: linking file `m4/ltversion.m4'
libtoolize: linking file `m4/lt~obsolete.m4'
configure.in:150: error: possibly undefined macro: dnl
      If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
      See the Autoconf documentation.
autoreconf: /Users/smu/gtk/inst/bin/autoconf failed with exit status: 1
*** Error during phase configure of gtk+: ########## Error running autoreconf -fis && ./configure --prefix /Users/smu/gtk/inst --libdir '/Users/smu/gtk/inst/lib' --with-gdktarget=quartz --disable-static *** [10/18]

  [1] Rerun phase configure
  [2] Ignore error and continue to build
  [3] Give up on module
  [4] Start shell
  [5] Reload configuration
  [6] Go to phase "wipe directory and start over"
  [7] Go to phase "clean"
  [8] Go to phase "distclean"
choice:
```

What can I do to solve this error ? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found a solution. I think that it's a problem with some versions of libraries.

Just bootstrap with --ignore-system to be sure that all libraries with their correct versions are correctly installed.

```
jhbuild bootstrap --ignore-system
```

Comment: How did you come up with that solution? I'm currently install Gnome on Mountain Lion and am having the same issue.