# How to correctly install pyGTK using macports?

Tags: python, pygtk, macports

My python code uses GTK for some GUI and now i need to run some of it on OSX (10.6 Snow Leopard and 10.7 Lion). Unfortunately, unofficial pyGTK [build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164949/where-is-pygtk-for-mac-os-x) crashes on window GTK windows resize, so i decided to test macports version. I installed python and pygtk via following macports commands:

```
sudo port install python26
sudo port select --set python python26
sudo port install py-gtk2
```

Running `python` from console correctly starts macports version of python. But trying to execute
`import gtk` or `import pygtk` fails with error that such package is not available :(.

I have a feeling that I missed something very simple to get all to work. Something like setting correct `site-package` for macports python or whatever. Maybe some guru may share a bit of wisdom?

UPDATE: Careful examination revealed that py-gtk2 was installed only into `/opt/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages`, leaving `.../python2.6/site-packages` and `.../python2.7/site-packages` blank. Running macports version of python 2.4 allows me to use pyGTK. But I want it with python 2.6 (preferred) or 2.7 :(.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Port name was incorrect. Correct ports are `py25-gtk` / `py26-gtk` / `py27-gtk`.

Updated: recently renamed to `py25-pygtk` / `py26-pygtk` / `py27-pygtk`

Comment: (Note: sorry for the formatting, I'm trying everything I can here to get a damn line break. I read the help and more section but oh well. I suppose I'll just leave the main comment alone...)

Looks like that may have changed. I tried to install py27-gtk (fresh macports install, ran selfupdate, on Mountain Lion) and got this:  Error: py27-gtk has been replaced by py27-pygtk; please install that port instead  Error: org.macports.configure for port py27-gtk returned: obsolete port  So I'll note this in the main answer if that's alright.

Answer (score 0):

Only py27-pygtk is valid macport now

```
sudo port install py27-pygtk
```