# import gtk not working on mac

Tags: python, macos, pygtk, macports, importerror

I am new to Python and mac OS. I've Installed `py27-pygtk-2.24.0_3` from `macports`.
I tried to run the following:

```
#!/opt/local/bin/python2.7
import gtk
window=gtk.Window()
window.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
button=gtk= gtk.Button("Hello")
window.add(button)

window.show_all()\gtk.main()
```

I am executing the file through Python Launcher and get this error:

```
Import error:No module named GTK
```

I spent the whole day searching for answer. Can someone help me and make it work?

Comment: How have you installed `py27-pygtk`? Where was it installed into? By any chance do you have several `Python` versions installed on your system? [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7317921/3903832) might prove useful.

Comment: I typed in Terminal: $ sudo port install py27-pygtk, I am not sure if another Python was installed. Existing Python is ver 2.7.5

Comment: What is the output of `port select --list python` and `port select --show python`?

Comment: So, should I install another Python to make it work? Using those two lines used in the link. Can I use existing Python instead?

Comment: Those lines don't install anything. They just show which versions you have currently installed, and which one is the default.

Comment: Available versions for python:
 none (active)
 python25-apple
 python26-apple
 python27
 python27-apple
pawels-mbp:~ paweliwaniuk$ port select --show python
The currently selected version for 'python' is 'none'.

Comment: I just input: pawels-mbp:~ paweliwaniuk$ sudo port select --set python python27
Password:
Selecting 'python27' for 'python' succeeded. 'python27' is now active.
pawels-mbp:~ paweliwaniuk$ port select --show python
The currently selected version for 'python' is 'python27'.

Comment: Tried to run original script and still the same error message

Comment: You have to reinstall `pygtk` onto that version. Please see my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should clean up all old installations of `pygtk` which might be corrupt:

```
sudo port clean --all -f py27-pygtk
```

Now, since you have several versions of `Python` installed on your system, as shown by the command:

```
port select --list python
```

you have to select the correct one into which `macports` will install `pygtk`, as follows:

```
sudo port select --set python python27
```

Only then you can install `pygtk` as follows:

```
sudo port install py27-pygtk
```

Comment: sudo port install py27-pygtk
Warning: xcodebuild exists but failed to execute
Warning: Xcode does not appear to be installed; most ports will likely fail to build.
--->  Computing dependencies for py27-pygtk
--->  Cleaning py27-pygtk
--->  Scanning binaries for linking errors
--->  No broken files found.

Comment: Follow [these steps](https://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.html#installing.xcode) in order to install `xcode`.

Comment: Is there anything else to be set in Mac? I bought it 2 days ago, and I am not familiar yet with OS at all.

Comment: I don't own a Mac so I have no idea. Try googling something like _configure new mac_ and see what's relevant for you. Whenever I get a new OS, I learn it for the first few months and reinstall from fresh once I'm confident enough not to repeat the mistakes I've done the first time around. Are you still getting an error when attempting to import `gtk`?

Comment: I am going mad slowly. I can not install Xcode because my OS is 10.9.3 and needs to be 10.9.4 up. Do I need to update OS?

Comment: If it doesn't let you install on 10.9.3, I guess you should. I think it's a good idea anyway, and shouldn't take too long.

Comment: Have you upgraded your OS? Was the installation of `pygtk` successful this time around?

Comment: I gave up. OS was upgraded, Xcode installed, I went through dozen tutorials still nothing. At the moment I installed Eclipse with PyDev, I am able to run create Python programs... but can not create  PyDev project. When New project is created I can not add PyDev module using PyDev perspective. PyDev icon is there but when press OK window is gone. So I can not type anything in the project. As well I can not open this project again and create new with the same name. Is it some kind of sign to leave Python alone?

Comment: Oh, sorry to hear. What was the problematic output regarding `pygtk` installation? I expected it to work properly the second time around...

Comment: Import error:No module named GTK. Do you have any experience with Eclipse and PyDev?

Comment: No, sorry... But the `import error` surprises me. Were there any errors on the reinstallation of `pygtk` itself with `sudo port select --set python python27` and `sudo port install py27-pygtk`?

Comment: That's why I gave up, installation without any errors, but result the same. I spent hours trying. But with Eclipse I hope more luck

Comment: I see, maybe try cleaning up the old installation before, with the command `sudo port clean --all -f py27-pygtk` and then reinstall it again.

Comment: Yes now I can import GTK. It was long way. Thank you

Comment: Great, I've updated my answer to reflect our new findings for future reference. Please consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) it by clicking the check-mark that is to the left of the answer. Note that there is absolutely no obligation to do this.