# How do you install gtk for python (without getting lots of errors)

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, macports

NOTE: This post has several developments noted in the EDITs section at the bottom.

I can't figure out why my small program is throwing an error.

It seems like lot's of other people are having this same issue.  I just read [this article](http://buffalothedestroyer.blogspot.com/2009/07/blog-post.html) which basically says installing gtk is impossible.  Surely that is not the case...

Also, this one: [import gtk not working on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26058539/import-gtk-not-working-on-mac?rq=1)

Let's figure this out.

I think the most relevant line from the console readout (printed below) is `GtkWarning: Screen for GtkWindow not set; you must always set a screen for a GtkWindow before using the window`.  I've googled the hell out of this, but I can't figure out how to "set a screen..." before using the window

`which python` give `/opt/local/bin/python`, which is what I want, I think, as I am using libraries installed through macports.

I've followed the procedure given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26058539/import-gtk-not-working-on-mac) post, so I am sure I'm running `py27-pygtk`.

```
#!/opt/local/bin/python2.7
import gtk, os

window = gtk.Window()
window.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)

image = gtk.Image()
window.add(image)
image.set_from_file(os.path.join("data", "image1.jpg"))

window.show_all()
gtk.main()
```

This is the console readout:

```
$ python imageHello.py

** (process:691): WARNING **: Trying to register gtype 'GMountMountFlags' as enum when in fact it is of type 'GFlags'

** (process:691): WARNING **: Trying to register gtype 'GDriveStartFlags' as enum when in fact it is of type 'GFlags'

** (process:691): WARNING **: Trying to register gtype 'GSocketMsgFlags' as enum when in fact it is of type 'GFlags'
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:57: GtkWarning: could not open display
  warnings.warn(str(e), _gtk.Warning)
imageHello.py:4: Warning: invalid (NULL) pointer instance
  window = gtk.Window()
imageHello.py:4: Warning: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
  window = gtk.Window()
imageHello.py:11: GtkWarning: Screen for GtkWindow not set; you must always set
a screen for a GtkWindow before using the window
  window.show_all()
imageHello.py:11: GtkWarning: gdk_screen_get_default_colormap: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
  window.show_all()
imageHello.py:11: GtkWarning: gdk_colormap_get_visual: assertion 'GDK_IS_COLORMAP (colormap)' failed
  window.show_all()
imageHello.py:11: GtkWarning: gdk_screen_get_root_window: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
  window.show_all()
imageHello.py:11: GtkWarning: gdk_window_new: assertion 'GDK_IS_WINDOW (parent)' failed
  window.show_all()
Segmentation fault: 11
```

EDIT: I read somewhere (will post link as soon as I find it) that you need something called x11 in order to use gtk.  So I just ran `sudo port -v install xorg-server`.  This did not help.

EDIT2: Just downloaded [xquartz from their website](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/).  But then, and here's the key I think, I restarted my computer.  Now I am able to get my program to run properly.  However, I am still getting the following warning.  I have no idea what it means.  Any ideas?

```
$ python imageHello.py

** (process:312): WARNING **: Trying to register gtype 'GMountMountFlags' as enum when in fact it is of type 'GFlags'

** (process:312): WARNING **: Trying to register gtype 'GDriveStartFlags' as enum when in fact it is of type 'GFlags'

** (process:312): WARNING **: Trying to register gtype 'GSocketMsgFlags' as enum when in fact it is of type 'GFlags'
```

Comment: `GtkWarning: could not open display` is at least one, if not the, problem in your case. It seems your gtk is configured for X11 use, but you do not have an X server started. One way to get an X server is installing `xorg-server` from MacPorts, the other is installing [XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/). It doesn't matter which one you use, they are equal anyway. Either way requires that you log out and back in again after installation.

Comment: thank you so much.  Just now got the image to open up.  However, see EDIT 2.  I'm stilling getting a GtkWarning