# Run Jython and Python in one File

Tags: python, jython

I developed a project using python. Now i need a gui for that project. So i choose jython for gui(java swing). I also integrate theme in one code (existing project + gui(jython) code). When i run the file with the following command then it shows a syntax error

```
jython project.py
```

Error:

```
File "project.py", line 33
SyntaxError: 'with' will become a reserved keyword in Python 2.6
```

Line#33:

```
32 def _finished_loading(self, view, frame):
33        with open(self._file, 'w') as f:
```

When i run the existing project with python command then it runs ok. That means there is no problem with the project. And i assure you that gui(jython) code and integration are also fine.

Comment: What version of jython are you running?

Comment: @tkon thanks for quick reply.    Jython 2.5.1+ Python 2.7.3rc1
Ubuntu 11.10 64bit.

Comment: `from __future__ import with`  -- i'm not sure if `with` has been ported to Jython since it's at 2.5.1 and Python 2.6 is where `with` exists.

Comment: So what's your question -- don't run code that is incompatible with Python 2.5 -- don't use with

Comment: It seems you're using a version of Jython that is out of sync with the version of (C)Python that you wrote your code for. You'll need to back-port your code.

Comment: jython and python are not similar !! I just modified the line without with, now it is showing it     import gtk, urllib ImportError: No module named gtk  How can i integrate jython and python. I used python-webkit in my existing project

Comment: @tkone: it does in fact exist in Jython 2.5 if you use the import, though it's `import with_statement`, not `import with`.

Comment: @shantanu: `gtk` is not available in Jython, owing to the fact it was compiled for CPython. From http://www.jython.org/docs/library/indexprogress.html "...any Python that does not use C extensions should work on Jython."

Comment: @zigg what should i do now? i need gui. Problem is that this program must need to run in mac so i used cross platform jython. :(

Comment: @zigg ah yes `with_statement` -- it's been a while since i've had to import it.

Comment: @shantanu You might be able to get `gtk` working on OS X with CPython.  Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164949/where-is-pygtk-for-mac-os-x  But this is outside my expertise, so I cannot help.  Just know that if you go Jython, you'll need libraries that are available on Jython--it doesn't magically all CPython libraries available.

Comment: Why not continue to use cpython and Tkinter? It works fine on osx.

Answer (score 10):

Because `with` only just appeared in 2.5, you need a `from __future__` import:

```
from __future__ import with_statement
```

Then you can use your `with` statement.  It won't solve your other problems that cropped up in your comments, though...

Comment: Don't literally use the `...`.  Take the `from __future__` import and put it the incomplete source file you posted in the question.