# Fink can't resolve xcode dependency

Tags: xcode, macos, pygtk, fink

I just upgraded my xcode to 4.5.2 and ran

```
xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

but when I try to install pygtk, I get an error:

```
fink install pygtk2-gtk-py27
```

Output:

```
Information about 6815 packages read in 0 seconds.
Can't resolve dependency "xcode (>= 4.4)" for package "pixman-0.28.2-1" (no
matching packages/versions found)
Exiting with failure.
```

How do I correct this?  Also, I'm only trying to install pygtk this way because other ways for my mac haven't worked.  When I run the following with python:

```
import gtk
```

If I install with homebrew I get an error that says it can't find gtk.  When I install from macpkg as per the second answer in [where-is-pygtk-for-mac-os-x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164949/where-is-pygtk-for-mac-os-x) I get a segmentation fault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to upgrading my Xcode, it was necessary to install (again) Command Line tools.  For a description of this process, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9329325/1676002).